# Controller throwing error after adding hateoas support in a webflux app

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-webflux, spring-hateoas

When adding RepresentationModel to my entity, I am receiving an error whilst getting data from the db. I can post with no problem.

```
@Document(collection = "airports")
public class Airport extends RepresentationModel<Airport> {

  @Id
  private String icao;

}
```

and the controller

```
@GetMapping
public Flux<Airport> getAirports() {
  return repository.findAll();
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set property links because no setter, no wither and it's not part of the persistence constructor public com.example.mongo.entities.Airport()!
```

I thought that maybe it could have been a problem with lombok, and implemented the constructors, getters and setters manually, but to no avail!

Comment: I am getting the same exception when running a latest spring boot app.

Comment: It has nothing to do with lombok, it's just that you are extending `RepresentationModel` which have a `private final List<Link> links`, you can check my answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63693623/cannot-perform-get-request-on-spring-hateoas-application?answertab=active#tab-top)